# LaTeX compilation error in pdf bookdown package, but HTML output works perfectly

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I'm using the R Bookdown package along with TinyTex to generate both HTML and PDF formats of the book I'm writing.

Before today, everything worked. But now I am now encountering a Latex compilation error to produce the bookdown PDF, and I can't figure out why. Here is the error:

```
! Package array Error: Empty preamble: `l' used. 
Error: LaTeX failed to compile Shor-Book.tex.
```

I do have a non-empty preamble, which contains this:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Font selection for XeLaTeX; see fontspec.pdf for documentation
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % to support TeX conventions like ``---''
\usepackage{xunicode} % Unicode support for LaTeX character names (accents, European chars, etc)
\usepackage{xltxtra} % Extra customizations for XeLaTeX
```

_output.yml has the following entries for pdf_book:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  latex_engine: xelatex
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  citation_package: natbib
  mainfont: Crimson Pro
  sansfont: Source Sans Pro
  monofont: Ubuntu Mono
  extra_dependencies: ["flafter"]
  keep_tex: yes
  dev: "cairo_pdf"
```

The compilation log just repeats the error. Oddly, Build a book -> pdf_document compiles (though without the custom fonts I set up in the YAML).

The HTML bookdown output works without a problem.

I am running R 4.0.4 under Ubuntu 21.04. I have the latest versions of all R packages, and I have updated TinyTex packages as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. One of the R code chunks loaded some data to display a table. For some reason, that data became zero length. Once I regenerated the data correctly, I was able to compile the book. Odd that HTML worked and PDF did not.

For those of you in a similar bind -- move the Rmd files out of the book directory and compile them one by one -- that will tell you which file has the problem. Then comment everything out, and uncomment line by line. This will allow you to zero in on the problem.